# Is there any advantage at using public wifi with tor?

Tags: anonymity

consider these two scenarios:

1) You use tor on a private network (ex: home wifi), you also use a VPN you trust as a second layer.

2) You use tor on a public network (ex: library), and a VPN you trust.

Assuming the VPN never disconnects and there are no human errors, is there a advantage of using a public network? Does using a public network provide more anomitity or is it the same as a using a private one?

Or is the only advantage of a public network that if something fails your real IP cannot be leaked?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your threat model.

Assuming a typical set-up of Tor browser bundle and a VPN for all traffic on your PC, using Tor through a VPN obscures the use of Tor to the local network, and to your ISP. Your VPN provider knows you are using Tor either way, but doesn't know what sites you visit.

Regarding private vs. public network: There could be many factors, and it again depends on who you want to be anonymous from, and what your risk tolerance is. How hard is it to obtain your identity from your private ISP IP address? How hard is it to access surveillance cameras (or your phone location, or your car license plates parked outside, or other data that can be correlated to your identity) in or near the public location?